# html - Layout breaks within a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I'm facing a problem with a piece of html and css code.
I need to place an hot spot over an image. I have no idea about the dimensions of the image, it can be small or big. With a combination of a container and a wrapper I scaled the big images to the page's width. This is also useful for small images, because they are centered to the page.

However when i'll add the hot spot code `<div id="hotspot-0" class="hotspot circle green" />`, the layout breaks. So far i haven't had any luck to solve this issue.

Link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHmz8/2/)

html code:

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img id="imgDisplay" src="http://wethecampbells.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/sun.jpg" />

        <div id="hotspot-container">
            <div id="hotspot-0" class="hotspot circle green" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
```

css code

```css
.page {
    width: 960px;
    margin:auto;
}

.imgContainer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    min-height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.imgWrapper {
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

#hotspot-container {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    border: 2px dotted white;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

.hotspot {  
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.hotspot:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.circle {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.green {
    background-color: #00a700;
    border: 2px solid #008000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #00a700;
}
```

js code

```js
$('#imgDisplay').click(function(e){
        var x = Math.round(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
        var y = Math.round(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);

        // get the real dimension of the image
        var w = document.getElementById("imgDisplay").naturalWidth;
        var h = document.getElementById("imgDisplay").naturalHeight;

        var spotWidth = $("#hotspot-container").width();
        x -= Math.round(spotWidth / 2);
        y -= Math.round(spotWidth / 2);

        x = x / w * 100;
        y = y / h * 100;

        $('#hotspot-container').css('left', "" + x + "%").css('top', "" + y + "%").css('visibility', 'visible');

    });
```

Comment: looks like working fine in chrome. what layout breaks you got?

Comment: [Here is a list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) of void elements using the HTML5 doctype. `<div>` is not a void element. Use `<div id="hotspot-0" class="hotspot circle green"></div>`

Comment: It's not clear to me where this'hotspot' is supposed to be. Can you not position it using % values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` element isn't self closing tag, so `<div attributes=""/>` is not valid. Try `<div></div>`